# C++ function to find maximum element of 3 arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, function, max

I'm currently learning arrays and how they work. I'm given the following function that is used to find the maximum elements in three different arrays, A, B and C:

```
void findMax(int A[], int B[], int C[])
{
    int maxA = A[0], maxB = B[0], maxC = C[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < MAX_LEN; i++)
    {
        if(maxA < A[i]) maxA = A[i];
        if(maxB < B[i]) maxB = B[i];
        if(maxC < C[i]) maxC = C[i];
    }
}
```

My goal is to figure out how to return all three values (maxA, maxB, maxC) without adding extra arguments. I'm allowed to change the return type and I can write code outside the function.

My first thought was to change void into int and create a new array that has those three max values. However, I think I need pointers to return arrays and we haven't learned that yet.

Comment: Have you learned `struct`?

Comment: `struct Trio { int maxA, maxB, maxC; };` - One of those would probably come in handy, particularly for your return value.

Comment: @WhozCraig thanks for the idea! Would I write struct Trio outside the function and then change void to Trio?

Comment: @trungnt Yes.  Then in the code that calls `findMax()` you would have something like `Trio values = findMax(a,b,c);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to approach this.

## The Traditional Approach (Arrays)

The easiest way is to make the function return an `int[]`. This gives back all of the values easily and in a very concise format. However, the `int[]` type cannot guarantee that its size is 3 or that it contains what you claim it contains, so this is not a very type-friendly approach.

## The OO Approach (Structs)

Most JAVA enthusiasts will tell you to make a struct or a class that encapsulates the idea, such as this.

```
struct MaxVals {
    int maxA;
    int maxB;
    int maxC;
    // Possibly a constructor here
};
```

This is still a very memory-efficient solution and is much cleaner than the array approach. It also has the benefit of being more type-safe; you can't make a `MaxVals` with four or two `int`s now; it's guaranteed at compile-time to have 3. However, this is bulky. It requires you to define a new type, completely outside of your function, that will only ever be used in this one case.

## The Modern Approach (Tuples)

This is a new feature of C++, adapted from Python and Haskell, so it's only available in C++11, which has limited support across compilers. Tuples are a new data structure in the `tuple` header which can guarantee heterogeneous, fixed-size data structures of any types you specify at compile-time. You would set your return type to `std::tuple<int, int, int>` and initialize the structure with `std::make_tuple(maxA, maxB, maxC)`.

This approach has the same memory advantages and guarantees as the struct approach but without all the overhead and boilerplate of declaring a one-use type. This would be the ideal approach for a problem like this, if your compiler supports it.

Comment: Or you can use a `std::array` or `std::vector`

Comment: `which has limited support across compilers` Not really true now that it is 2015 almost all major compilers are mostly/fully c++11 compliant.

Comment: Thanks for taking the  time to write out a full fleshed explanation with different approaches. Much appreciated! I'm going to go with the OO approach since I'm familiar with structs. I'm still very new to programming as a whole, so there's lots I didn't learn about, including tuple. I'll look forward to learning that sooner or later.

Comment: @NathanOliver you are fortunate to live in an ideal world. I live in a world of multimillion dollar clients with Service Level Agreements carrying hefty penalties and leave management paralyzed. I'm on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5.8 w/GCC 4.1.2 (C++98; the C++11 version is GCC 4.8.1 released w/RHEL 7). We can't update the development box because it has to be on the same OS as the integration, QA, acceptance, staging, and production boxes. Don't mean to sound like I'm whining, but I just wanted to point out that you can't assume everyone is using C++11 just because it's available for years.

Comment: This is a very misleading answer. First, you cannot return `int[]` from a function. You could return `int*`. I don't know what's "traditional" about this. Next, just because it's a struct doesn't make it OO. And lastly, a `tuple` **is** a struct. It's more convenient to use here since you don't need to write your own definition, but it's the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things, you can do:

The first is declare `maxA, maxB, maxC` out side the function (globally). Then access them in your findMax function and main function.

```
int maxA, maxB, maxC;  
void findMax(int A[], int B[], int C[])
{
    maxA = A[0], maxB = B[0], maxC = C[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < MAX_LEN; i++)
    {
        if(maxA < A[i]) maxA = A[i];
        if(maxB < B[i]) maxB = B[i];
        if(maxC < C[i]) maxC = C[i];
    }
}
```

The second is use structure.

```
    struct node
    {
        int maxA,maxB,maxC;
    };

    struct node findMax(int A[], int B[], int C[])
    {
        struct node Max_node;
        Max_node.maxA = A[0], Max_node.maxB = B[0], Max_node.maxC = C[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < MAX_LEN; i++)
        {
            if(Max_node.maxA < A[i]) Max_node.maxA = A[i];
            if(Max_node.maxB < B[i]) Max_node.maxB = B[i];
            if(Max_node.maxC < C[i]) Max_node.maxC = C[i];
        }
        return Max_node;
    }
```

P.S: you also could use pointers, but as you said you are unfamiliar with them, I used other ways.

Comment: You should avoid globals whenever possible.  The OP can change the return type so why not return a struct from the function.

Comment: Both of these approaches use global variables, which are very poor design and even poorer in C++, where there are some other problems in play.

Comment: Well, I know that. Just helping him to get things done.

Comment: And he has mentioned that he's unaware of pointers and at this point it is okay to avoid design issues.

Comment: Appreciate the answer. I think at this point in time, I'm going for the method that uses struct.